# QtCreator WYSIWYG quality

Tags: qt5, qt-creator

I am making my first steps with QtCreator and I see some issues. I designed a simple widget, see the image below. On this screenshot the bottom view is what I designed and the top view is the result of running the design. I say they are similar, but I expected more. It looks like the running version compresses the components. Is there something I should set in QtCreator?

I also attempted to check the functionality of my widget, using debugging, but I receive the Warning 'This does not seem to be a "Debug" build.' Shall I set something to produce a debug build?

[image]

In the meantime I found out that if I do not put the widgets in a layout box,then I receive as output what I expected. Why a layout has such side effect?

Also, in the meantime I added some signal/slot connections. Since I did, I am presented with error message `ui_registerwidget.h:13: error: QtWidgets/QAction: No such file or directory`. It is a file/code generated by the QtCreator.